# IIS Worker Processes (w3wp.exe) with high handle counts

Tags: .net, iis, memory-leaks, handle, w3wp

Our IIS Worker Processes have high and steadly rising handle counts. The Thread Count seems to be stable but the Handle Count keep rising until the AppPool is shutdown because of inactivity.

For Testing purposes we configured a simple web application (just an .html file with text) with its own AppPool. If the html file is called directly -> no problem. As soon as a page is called that doesn't exist the handles start rising. The high Handle Count only occurs in Integrated Mode with 4.0 - Classic and / or 2.0 dont have the problem.

The leaking Handles seem to be Event Handles. This is from a Memory Report:

[image]

The exact same test was done on another server and the problem does not occur. I already tried to use windbg and opened a microsoft support case but no results.

Comment: try turning off module by module in your sample application, like Urlrewriting, authorization etc to isolate the issue

Comment: also, you can try using `ProcMon` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to understand which particular handles are being created - it may be really helpful to isolate the issue